# How to start android service from another Android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having a problem starting a service from another Android app (API 17).
However, if I do run 'am' from the shell, the service starts fine.

```
# am startservice com.xxx.yyy/.SyncService
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.xxx.yyy/.SyncService }
(service starts fine at this point)
# am to-intent-uri com.xxx.yyy/.SyncService
intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;
category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;
component=com.xxx.yyy/.SyncService;end
```

So, it doesn't look like I'm missing anything from the intent when I do the same in the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", ".SyncService"));
ComponentName c = ctx.startService(i);
if (c == null) { Log.e(TAG, "failed to start with "+i); }
```

What I get is (the service is not running at that time):

```
E/tag( 4026): failed to start with Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
cmp=com.xxx.yyy/.SyncService }
```

I don't have an intent filter on the service, and I don't want to set one up, I'm really trying to understand what am I doing wrong starting it through its component name, or what may be making it impossible to do so.

Comment: refer http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html

Comment: @Richa This page has examples with using Intent.setClassName(), but it doesn't really answer my specific question...

Comment: Also, check logcat for any meaningful errors (don't filter the logcat as you might miss something valuable/important)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should be able to start your service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.SyncService"));
ComponentName c = ctx.startService(i);
```

You don't need to set ACTION or CATEGORY if you are specifying a specific component. Make sure that your service is properly defined in the manifest.

Comment: Funny thing is, if I use i.setClassName(...) (and set the name/category), it works. The intent data that is printed out to the log is exactly the same. I'm just confused as to why the intent data printed by am seems to be the same as mine when I use setComponent(), yet one does start the service, and the other doesn't...

Comment: In your manifest, you have `package="xxx.yyy"` and in your code you use `"com.xx.yyy"`, is this a typo?

Comment: Also, in your manifest, on your `<service>` definition, you've set `exported="false"`. This means that the `Service` cannot be started by other applications.

Comment: package name is a typo. Thank you for pointing "exported" out - I'll fix that. However, "exported" wouldn't cause the problems I was seeing, as intent wouldn't even resolve to a service. Using setClassName(), as I said, "worked", but caused a security exception, where using setComponent() just returned null on attempting to start the service.

Comment: Were both these calls (`setClassName()` and `setComponent()`) made from with this application's package? Or from another application?

Comment: Hi, `i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", ".SyncService"));` doesn't work. only fully qualified name works `i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.yyy.SyncService"));` , kindly update.

Comment: @DavidWasser  It works for me (Thanks)  But I want to send data to the service with ```      start.putExtra("LAUNCHER_COMMAND_CLOSE" , true);
``` but When I get this intent in ```onStartCommand``` is null all the time!

Comment: @Ehsan please open a new question for this problem. Asking a question in a comment isn't helpful and  you won't get the attention you may need.

Comment: To add to it, if the app and the service are in different packages, the code should be
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("app.package", "service.package"));

Comment: @Vinayaka actually no. The first parameter to `new ComponentName()` is the package name of **the `Service`** and the second parameter is the fully qualified class name of **the `Service`**.

Comment: what if i have a service with "abc.123.a" package name and the app name is "app.name.full". ComponentName("app.full.name", "abc.123.a") correct??

Comment: DavidWasser, I think @Vinayaka is correct on this one, as exhibited by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272031/cannot-bind-to-exported-android-service). Or can you support your statement with documentation?

Comment: @HansBrende sorry if my comment is confusing. The first parameter is the **Android package name** of the app containing the `Service`. It isn't the **Java package name** of the `Service` class. Your linked question has also been resolved as it seems that OP changed his package names causing confusion. My comment was a response to Vinayaka's comment at 22:00 which had the **`service.package`** as the second parameter which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes much more sense. And yes, I am aware, as the OP is me :) And oops, yeah he was: I think I saw "service.package" and read "service.class". Was mainly focused on the app.package part due to my own issue.

Comment: any way if instead of service we open JobIntentService ?

Comment: @ralphgabb I don't understand your comment. Please open a new question as adding a comment to this answer isn't likely to get you the attention you need to solve your problem.

Comment: It may be worth including a snippet for the manifest as well as specifying which manifest needs to be updated.

Comment: I have app A (which service I want to call) and app B (from which I call app A) so when app target api 30 in app B It can not call service of app A. but when I make target 29 it's work any solution for this?

Comment: @bdevloper Please open a new question. Asking this in a comment on an existing question isn't helpful.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to David Wasser's answer to make it work when targeting API 30 and above you also have to add either:

Required package name in queries tag in manifest:

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.service.owner.app" />
</queries>
```

or permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

[Additional info on package visibility changes here](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

Answer (score 4):

Start your service like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("pkg", "cls"));
ComponentName c = getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(intent);
```

btw you actually need to use the applicationId, instead of the pkg. it can be found in the app gradle. I was struggling with that mistake for hours!

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.zzz"
}
```

the cls is the name of your service declared in the manifest. example: com.xxx.yyy.yourService.

```
 <service android:name="com.xxx.yyy.yourService"
android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: You and me both, mate. Thank you!