# how another app execute service programming on android?

Tags: android

I know another app execute on android

`Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("another pacakge name");
startActivity(intent);`

this way `another app execute in main app`

but I want In main app, another app execute service

my main app use `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

after main app start, execute service B app.

it is programming possible?

please advice for me

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.yyy","com.xxx.yyy.SyncService"));
ComponentName c = ctx.startService(intent);
```

This is answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316232/how-to-start-android-service-from-another-android-app)