# Android: IntentService and OS versions

Tags: android, task, android-4.4-kitkat, intentservice

I have an intent service I am starting from a normal service, which was created by an activity, which then finishes.

reference: [Android: Switch back to Chrome from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526316/android-switch-back-to-chrome-from-app)

So on Android KitKat, when I swipe the activity away (which has already called finish()) out of the task manager, the intentservice stops. But on 5.02 it keeps running.

Is this a known thing, or what? I thought intent service's are supposed to keep on running.

Comment: intent service is background worker thread, which runs seperately from main thread. Once it done with his job it will get finished autometically.

Comment: i have the service continuing indefinitely though. At the end of it's main function, I check a variable and if it's true, call the function again, repeat. So it is supposed to stay alive forever, and it does unless as mentioned, I swipe the task away on 4.4. Not a big deal because I check to see if the service is started from previous service. If not, start it...but I was just curious as to the different behavior on the different OS's.

Comment: okay got it, so while you do swipe it will kill your entire process that includes your service too. but if your service is sticky service it will restart automatically.

Is this a case? I am not confident on behavior on the different os, it will behave same in each os as its part of Framework.

Comment: No, I am saying swiping away the 'finished' activity kills the service on kitkat, but the same swiping does not kill the service on lollipop

Comment: Please can you post your code.

Comment: I am trying but I can't seem to add line breaks. The help says to add 2 spaces at the end of a sentence to add the break, but that isn't working for me.  This is supposed to be a new line.

Comment: send me code @kjthumbar@gmail.com,
as per my understanding of android framework, what you are observing is not possible. but I am not sure about it so let me test that code and will inform you what is going on.