# Send Intent from Activity to Service (TileService)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, binding

I tried to send an Intent from Activity to Service (one direction), but somehow it does not invoke onStartCommand function.

---

Here is my code for the Activity:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(); 
serviceIntent.setClassName("com.xx.pak", "com.xx.pak.MyService.act");
serviceIntent.putExtra("UserChoice", userChoice);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

---

Here is my code for the Service:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        switch (action) {
            case "com.xx.pak.MyService.act":
            userChoice = intent.getIntExtra("UserChoice", 0);
            break;
        default:
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            break;
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

---

One possible solution can be add service to manifest, but they are two different applications and I'm not sure how to include each other in the main manifest.

Also, if sending intents does not work, I may consider using broadcast to communicate. I'm new to Android, please let me know if I am on the correct path. Thanks.

Comment: Add the manifest entry of `com.xx.pak.MyService.act` in question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start android service from another Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316232/how-to-start-android-service-from-another-android-app)

Comment: I tried to added com.xx.pak.MyService.act into my intent-filter, it does not work. Same with the link that you sent, I tried the ComponentName before posting my question, it just crashed my app :(

Comment: Well if you tried the solution and app crashed . Then add the crash report with question . also mention the API level you are testing on .