# Getting a result back from a service which is not part of the same application

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

Overview of my use-case :

> I have an application, which contains a service `SignInService`. This service accepts login credentials, initiates authentication (by
>   hitting a 3rd party API) and gets the result (success/failure).
>   I
>   have some applications say, `App1` (having `Activity1`) and `App2`
>   (`Activity2`), both of which have a UI and basically start
>   `SignInService` with the login credentials and wait for the result of
>   authentication. Both of these activities will then dynamically change
>   the UI based on the result.

I have done some research and found some solutions none of which seem to apply to my situation :

- **Solution** : Sending a broadcast from `SignInService` and receiving it in my applications using `BroadcastReceivers`.
  **Problem** : This won't be giving the result back to the activity that initiated the service and is waiting to change it's UI based on the result.
- **Solution** : Using `ResultReceiver` callbacks. 
  **Problem** : Works with activities and services in same application.

Is there another way to implement this functionality ? I have explored both Services and BroadcastReceivers and didn't seem to find a solution (maybe I missed something) . 
**p.s :** I have not included any code because I don't think this problem is code specific. Also, I'm not really bent on using `Service` to perform the sign-in and want to my options open to all kinds of solutions.

Comment: Though you have mentioned that you don’t want to use service strictly. But want to confirm, is there any specific reason why you have highly modular code? Like UI in different apps and logic to authenticate the user in different app? On a side note, services are used for heavy operations like downloads, uploads, heavy background processing, etc. For simple tasks like making an API call (generally having timeouts of not more than 10 seconds) Services are not required.

Comment: Okay, consider some applications like `app1` that needs the user to have a facebook account. So when the user opens `app1`, the application will ask the user to login (is he wasn't already). For this, `app1` obtains user credentials and uses facebook api to authenticate and based on result allows/disallows the user access to the app. Now I also want to allow the user to be able to just add a facebook account from settings and so he doesn't has to login from `app1`. Here I wan't to have a common signin functionality which can be invoked from wherever.

Comment: Facebook has a confirmation page, which is basically an activity where it performs authentication and returns the result. So thats basically startActivityForResult . So in your use case if there is a possibility of using activity then probably you have to do that. otherwise you have to bind service to your calling activity.

Comment: That's issue, executing everything in background without disturbing UI except for reflecting result. Can you elaborate more on how I can receive result from the bound service ?

Comment: You can simply [bind a service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#java) to your connection and set a callback to listen for response. This is just like Fragment-Activity sort of interaction. Try it out, let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: From what I see, in my client activity class I have to instantiate `SignInService` or pass SignInService.class to intent in order to be able to bind to `SignInService`. This gives me an impression this requires the client activity class and service class to reside in the same package.

Comment: you might want to consider this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349791/5471104

Comment: I used AIDL to achieve this. I create the API and Callback .aidl files in a library and used the library dependency in the client apps and service app to utilize the stubs. The service app implements the stub methods and maintains a callback instance which it obtains from the service through a registerCallback method. When operation is complete, it invokes a callback method with the result which is implemented in the client and contains the logic to modify the UI based on the result.