# Starting a service of another Android app into my own app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-service

I am running a service of an android app from the shell with `am startservice`. All works as it should.

```
am startservice -a com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE --ef a 1 --ef b 2
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to start the service of another android app without being the developer? 
According to this link it's possible:
[How to start android service from another Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316232/how-to-start-android-service-from-another-android-app)

But I don't quite get how to do it.

This is the code I'm using in the `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.anotherdeveloper.app", "com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"));
ComponentName c = getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(intent);
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I've added this:

```
  <service
        android:name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

But it shows me an error in the manifest because of course Android Studio can't find the package name of this app installed on my phone.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Martin Marconcini, this is the code I'm using:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.anotherdeveloper.app","com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"));
  intent.putExtra("cty", 4);
  intent.putExtra("stt", 2);
  startService(intent);
```

And this is the service in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.General">
  <intent-filter>
    <action name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE_ALT"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.TERMINATE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it solely depends on 3rd party decision (what service creators wrote in corresponding `android:exported`)

More details here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

Comment: Since I am able to to start the service from the shell, does that not mean that the value of `android:exported` is `true` and therefore that this service is intended for external use?

Comment: Yes if you can start it in command line you can use it in your code BUT are you sure you can start it in command line? Your code starts it as foreground service (correct) but your command line does not. I don't think your command line (the way it was specified) should work.

Comment: An example: `am start-foreground-service com.anotherdeveloper.app/.SERVICE`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in command line and it works. Then maybe the problem is I shouldn't start it as foreground service?
Also, what I should add in the manifest.xml since it gives me an error on `android:name="com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"`?

Comment: You shouldn't change you app's manifest in order to invoke 3rd party service. However I'm not sure about "not starting as foreground" - it depends on your device sdk version (startForegroundService requires min sdk to be 26, so if your device is say 21 it won't work)

Comment: Then in order to invoke a 3rd party service I would need only to create a new intent and then start the service? No need at all to edit my app's manifest? My phone is currently on Android 6.0, so sdk 23.
Another thing I'm wondering... how can I start the service with parameters like in the command line?

Comment: Yes exactly - no need to edit your own manifest. As you are on sdk 23, you should start service the old way (in fact, should use both ways depending on platform)

Comment: Ok, thank you, but how? This doesn't start the service:

`Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.anotherdeveloper.app", "com.anotherdeveloper.app.SERVICE"));
ComponentName c = getApplicationContext().startService(intent);`

And how should I pass the parameters like I did in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on your question inside the comments:

1. Yes, you can start the service if it's exported (and you said it was), so it should work.
2. To pass parameters via Intent, you need to use the "Extras". This is akin to the `-e` parameter you use in `adb shell am`.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putXXX(key, value)
```

You're going to get a lot of options (for each type) instead of XXX , for e.g.:

```
int value = 1;
i.putExtra("Key", value)

// or

String value = "X"
i.putExtra("Key", value)

// or

boolean value = true;
i.putExtra("Key", value)
```

They all work (make the keys unique of course).

Alternatively, you can pass a `Bundle` that contains a bunch.

```
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("x", "value");
        b.putInt("x", 1);
        b.putBoolean("x", true);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("theBundle", b);
```

In essence, it's all very Google/Java like, where consistency was *not* the key. ;)

(of course, if you pass a bundle, the *receiver* must know this so it can "get the bundle" out of extras, and then extract each key/value.

Put it differently, a Bundle is a glorified Dictionary that supports different types and where all things must be `Parcelable`. So it's a key/value store that must be parcelable.

Intent data size (for extras) has a limit of X (can't remember if it's 1mb or what) but you can't just serialize 1 terabyte of information and toss it via intent. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can you check the updated question? I added the code and a bit of the AndroidManifest.xml. It seems you were right, there isn't a `exported="true"` in that service... this is very weird, since I am able to start the service from the shell, does not that mean the service is intended for external use?

Comment: question: did you try to do change `getApplicationContext().` to `this.` since you *are* in an activity/context already. Does that work?

Comment: I've tried both `getApplicationContext().startService(intent)` and `this.startService(intent)`.

Comment: Hmm all right, I'll take a look today to see if I can find anything. I haven't really started a lot of services via the cmd line in the past couple of years; this is the kind of thing that is usually specific to a project where you do this a lot for whatever reason and when you're done, you never touch that again. So I'd like to make sure I'm not giving bad advice here.